# Safari not loading javascript files from IIS on local network

Tags: javascript, iis, safari, mobile-safari

I have a website written with Angular. I have built it and put it on my Windows IIS, and it's working fine locally or from other Windows machines on the network after I access it via `http://my-ip` (where `my-ip` is the local address of the Windows machine running IIS.

When I try to load this website from iOS safari, or even from safari on MacOS on the same network I get a blank white page.

When I use the safari web developers tools on MacOS to inspect the page I see the HTML of the page, and under network traffic I see that the page was downloaded along with the CSS - however the javascript file were not downloaded (and those nothing was loaded to the page - blank white page).

If I add a javascript file that is not related to Angular with just an alert in it - it's also not executed. However if I put a script with alert in the HTML page itself it is loaded.

What is the cause of it? How do I make it work under MacOS and iOS? I searched for similar cases but could not find an answer. Only information about safari sandbox which does not explain how to fix the problem, and I'm not sure it's one of the same.

Comment: Have you get IIS static content feature installed? Besides, did you see any exception in console tab?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. The console tab is clean of messages. Why would IIS static content be required for just Safari? As I have mentioned above it works on other Windows PCs.

Comment: Could you check  what's the content-type of javascript file in IOS? I was thinking that IIS only decide static file content-type with static content extension so maybe there was something wrong with the header. Besides, have you tried to disable IIS compression?